# Unable to get multiple rows returned from a SELECT to summarize correctly by a specific column

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, case, average

I have an Oracle table that looks like this:

```
     test_time              test_name    test_type     test_location    test_value
     -----------------      ---------    ---------     -------------    ----------
     09/22/20 12:00:05         A            RT             Albany           200
     09/22/20 12:00:05         A            RT             Chicago          500
     09/22/20 12:00:05         B            RT             Albany           400
     09/22/20 12:00:05         B            RT             Chicago          300
     09/22/20 12:00:05         A            WPL            Albany           1500
     09/22/20 12:00:05         A            WPL            Chicago          2300
     09/22/20 12:00:05         B            WPL            Albany           2100
     09/22/20 12:00:05         B            WPL            Chicago          1900
     09/22/20 12:05:47         A            RT             Albany           300
     09/22/20 12:05:47         A            RT             Chicago          400
     09/22/20 12:05:47         B            RT             Albany           600
     09/22/20 12:05:47         B            RT             Chicago          500
     09/22/20 12:05:47         A            WPL            Albany           1700
     09/22/20 12:05:47         A            WPL            Chicago          2000
     09/22/20 12:05:47         B            WPL            Albany           1800
     09/22/20 12:05:47         B            WPL            Chicago          2400
```

I want to run a SELECT against this table that will show me the average value of each location cited for a specific test_type (in this case, "RT") over the last 11 minutes, summarized by test_name. "11 minutes" is used to ensure that I will retrieve rows from at least two iterations of a script that inserts the records every five minutes.

I'd like the results of a SELECT statement against this table to look like this:

```
     test_name      albany_avg_val     chicago_avg_val  
     ---------      --------------     ---------------  
      A                 250                450         
      B                 500                400
```

(NOTE: the "albany_avg_val" for test_name "A" reflects the average value of the "test_value" values associated with the two iterations of test_name "A"/test_type "RT"/test_location "Albany" that ran at 12:00 and 12:05).

The SELECT statement I've built so far looks like this:

```
SELECT
   test_name,
   CASE test_location
      WHEN 'Albany'
         THEN ROUND(AVG( test_value ),0) albany_avg_val
      WHEN 'Chicago'
         THEN ROUND(AVG( test_value ),0) chicago_avg_val
   END
FROM
   test_table
WHERE
   test_type = 'RT' AND test_time > sysdate - interval '11' minute;
```

...but it's not working as expected. Could someone help me with what I may be missing, please?

Comment: Can there be more values of `test_location`, for which you want additional columns in the result? Or is it always going to be just the two - `Albany` and `Chicago`?

Comment: @MartinHeralecký: Additional values (cities) may be added in the near future; up to eight cities in all may be used for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pivot clause was designed exactly for such things: the following query aggregates for all `test_type` values:

```sql
select *
from (select test_name, test_location, test_type, test_value from test_table)
pivot(
  avg(test_value)
  for test_location in ('Albany ' as Albany,'Chicago' as Chicago)
);
```

Results:

```
TEST_NAME TEST_TYPE     ALBANY    CHICAGO
--------- --------- ---------- ----------
A         RT               250        450
B         RT               500        400
A         WPL             1600       2150
B         WPL             1950       2150
```

Or if you want to filter only `RT`:

```
select *
from (select test_name, test_location, test_value from test_table where test_type='RT')
pivot(
  avg(test_value)
  for test_location in ('Albany ' as Albany,'Chicago' as Chicago)
);
```

Results:

```
TEST_NAME     ALBANY    CHICAGO
--------- ---------- ----------
B                500        400
A                250        450
```

Full test case with sample data:

```sql
with test_table(test_time,test_name,test_type,test_location,test_value) as (
select to_date('09/22/20 12:00:05','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'A', 'RT ', 'Albany ', 200  from dual union all
select to_date('09/22/20 12:00:05','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'A', 'RT ', 'Chicago', 500  from dual union all
select to_date('09/22/20 12:00:05','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'B', 'RT ', 'Albany ', 400  from dual union all
select to_date('09/22/20 12:00:05','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'B', 'RT ', 'Chicago', 300  from dual union all
select to_date('09/22/20 12:00:05','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'A', 'WPL', 'Albany ', 1500 from dual union all
select to_date('09/22/20 12:00:05','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'A', 'WPL', 'Chicago', 2300 from dual union all
select to_date('09/22/20 12:00:05','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'B', 'WPL', 'Albany ', 2100 from dual union all
select to_date('09/22/20 12:00:05','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'B', 'WPL', 'Chicago', 1900 from dual union all
select to_date('09/22/20 12:05:47','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'A', 'RT ', 'Albany ', 300  from dual union all
select to_date('09/22/20 12:05:47','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'A', 'RT ', 'Chicago', 400  from dual union all
select to_date('09/22/20 12:05:47','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'B', 'RT ', 'Albany ', 600  from dual union all
select to_date('09/22/20 12:05:47','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'B', 'RT ', 'Chicago', 500  from dual union all
select to_date('09/22/20 12:05:47','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'A', 'WPL', 'Albany ', 1700 from dual union all
select to_date('09/22/20 12:05:47','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'A', 'WPL', 'Chicago', 2000 from dual union all
select to_date('09/22/20 12:05:47','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'B', 'WPL', 'Albany ', 1800 from dual union all
select to_date('09/22/20 12:05:47','mm/dd/yy hh24:mi:ss'), 'B', 'WPL', 'Chicago', 2400 from dual 
)
select *
from (select test_name, test_location, test_type, test_value from test_table)
pivot(
  avg(test_value)
  for test_location in ('Albany ' as Albany, 'Chicago' as Chicago)
);
```

Comment: After reviewing and testing the solutions with my team, the "pivot" approach bubbled to the top. We haven't used "pivot" before with Oracle queries, and we thought this was a good use case to build off of. We just had to add the "test_time" condition (last 11 minutes). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
select
    test_name,
    round(avg(case when test_location = 'Albany'  then test_value end)) albany_avg_val
    round(avg(case when test_location = 'Chicago' then test_value end)) chicago_avg_val
from test_table
where
   test_type = 'rt' 
   and test_location in ('Albany', 'Chicago')
   and test_time > sysdate - 11 / 24 / 60
group by test_name
```

That is:

- use `group by`!
- move the `case` expression *within* aggregate function `avg()`
- each column should be separated - a conditional expression cannot generate two columns

And also...:

- prefiltering in the `where` clause improves the efficiency of the query
- it is safer to use "numeric" date arithmetics against `sysdate` (which is a `date`); if you want interval arithmetics, use `systimestamp` instead
- `0` is the default precision for `round()`

Comment: This is a good approach to the issue in question. Our team opted to use a different answer instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Seems you need conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT
      test_name,
      AVG(CASE 
          WHEN test_location='Albany'
          THEN ROUND( test_value ) END) AS albany_avg_val,
      AVG(WHEN test_location='Chicago'
          THEN ROUND( test_value ) END) AS chicago_avg_val
 FROM test_table
WHERE test_type = 'RT' 
  AND test_time > sysdate - interval '11' minute;
GROUP BY test_name
```

*second argument(`0`) for `ROUND()` function is redundant.*

Answer (score 2):

please try something like this

````
SELECT
   test_name,
   ROUND(AVG(CASE when test_location='Albany'
         THEN  test_value 
         else null end),0) albany_avg_val,
 ROUND(AVG(CASE when test_location='Chicago'
         THEN  test_value 
         else null end),0) Chicago_avg_val
 
FROM
   test_table
WHERE
   test_type = 'RT' AND test_time > sysdate - interval '11' minute
   group by test_name; ```
````